# How Java Garbage Collector recognizes the unreferenced objects?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Could someone explain me this garbage collection.

Comment: There are several algorithms available.I think this will help you .http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html

Comment: [Java Garbage Collection Basics](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

Comment: This is exactly one of those questions that need to stay open as it asks a general question about programming that can definitely help future visitors and people new to programming to learn these things. He is not the first to wonder this and will not be the last to ask this, now there is a reference to this question for future people to view. I do think an edit to the question will be needed for future reference, by removing the part about the interview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put: by traversing the graph of references and seeing which nodes are pointed to by references. The other objects (those which are not pointed to) are considered garbage and so they are marked as eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to `System.out.println()` the hashcodes of the unreferenced objects?

Comment: @kiltek Well, if you want to print their hash codes, it means you want to reference them, right? But they are not referenced so... I don't see a way to do this. I might be wrong but I doubt that.

Comment: But if the Garbage Collector knows how to find all referenced objects, it somehow still must have information about non-referenced objects, because it needs to distinguish between them?